# jQuery Filter divs By Class display restriction

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to filter some divs by their class, restrict the divs number to max 6 divs and  to make next/back buttons to browse within them if they are more than 6 divs.

Html is :
Category buttons :

```
            <div class="category-filter box">
                <a id="paste" class="button">Paste 2015</a>
                <a id="1mai" class="button">1 Mai</a>
            </div>
```

DIVS to be filtered:

```
 <div id="parent">
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>
............................
<div class="col-sm-4 1mai">1 MAI<div>
<div class="col-sm-4 1mai">1 MAI<div>
 ............................     
    </div>
```

Back / Next buttons

```
<ul class="pagination clearfix">
 <li class="prev"><a href="#">Inapoi</a></li>
 <li class="next"><a href="#">Inainte</a></li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery is:

```
var $items = $('.col-sm-4');
var $btns = $('.button').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $items.show();
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).show();
    $items.not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

The Category buttons "Paste 2015" and "1 Mai" are filering ( on button press it shows only the desired divs )

But i need to make work the back /next button and to restrict the max divs at 6 to be displayed at once.

Thanks.

Comment: `col-sm-4` elements not appear to have  `/` at closing `</div>` tag; see `<div class="col-sm-4 paste">PASTE<div>` ? See also `if (this.id == 'all')` ; `all` not appear as `id` of an element at OP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added class *all* to each of div items. Now it is easy to filter divs just by class. Divs are appended by numbers just to make page navigation obvious. There are no pretty styles, but it works fine.

```
<div class="category-filter box">
  <a id="all" class="button">[ALL]</a>
  <a id="paste" class="button">[Paste 2015]</a>
  <a id="1mai" class="button">[1 Mai]</a>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 9</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 10</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 11</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 12</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 13</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 paste all">PASTE 14</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 1mai all">1 MAI 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 1mai all">1 MAI 2</div>
</div>
<ul class="pagination clearfix">
  <li class="prev"><a href="#" id="prev_page">Prev</a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="#" id="next_page">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var page;
  var items = $('.col-sm-4');
  var filtered_items;
  var page_size = 6;

  function get_filtered_items(filter) {
    return items.filter('.'.concat(filter));
  }

  function show_page(page) {
    items.hide();
    filtered_items.slice(page * page_size, (page + 1) * page_size).show();

    if (page > 0) {
      $('#prev_page').show();
    } else {
      $('#prev_page').hide();
    }
    if (page < Math.ceil(filtered_items.length / page_size) - 1) {
      $('#next_page').show();
    } else {
      $('#next_page').hide();
    }
  }

  var btns = $('.button').click(function() {
    btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    page = 0;
    filtered_items = get_filtered_items(this.id);
    show_page(page);
  });

  $('#prev_page').click(function() {
    page--;
    show_page(page);
  });

  $('#next_page').click(function() {
    page++;
    show_page(page);
  });

  $('#all').click();
});
```